# How to extend an interface and pick all fields from another one?

Tags: typescript

Given the following interface

```
interface MyCustomInterface {
    aField: string;
}
```

and a library providing the following

```
type CommandData = Record<string, unknown>;

class Command<TData extends CommandData> {}
```

When creating a custom command I could go for

```
interface CustomCommandData extends CommandData {
    aField: string;
}

class CustomCommand extends Command<CustomCommandData> {}
```

But there is no need for `CustomCommandData` because I could simply use `MyCustomInterface` instead. E.g.

`class CustomCommand extends Command<MyCustomInterface> {}`

The compiler tells me that's not possible because

> TS2344: Type 'MyCustomInterface' does not satisfy the constraint 'CommandData'.   Index signature for type 'string' is missing in type 'MyCustomInterface'.

How can I modify `CustomCommandData` to

- pick all fields from `MyCustomInterface`
- extend `CommandData`

? I'm basically looking for something like

```
interface CustomCommandData extends CommandData where this extends MyCustomInterface {}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an [intersection type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#intersection-types) for this.

```
type CustomCommandData = CommandData & MyCustomInterface;
```

This creates a type that is assignable to both `CommandData` and `MyCustomInterface`.

#### Side note

If you're in control of the library that defines `CommandData`, there's options for that type which would prevent this kind of issue. If `CommandData` was defined to be `Record<string, any>` instead, `MyCustomInterface` would be assignable out of the box, while still preserving the limitation to only using "object types" due to the usage of `Record`.